# Remove duplicate URLs in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

This code giving me duplicate URLs, how do I filter them

```
sg = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.somewebsite")}):
    print(url['href'])
    sg.append(url['href'])
print(sg)
```

Comment: thanx it did work

Answer (score 1):

You can check if url is already inserted on list

```
sg = []
for url in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.somewebsite")}):
    href = url['href'])
    print(href)
    if href not in sg:
        sg.append(href)
print(sg)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` instead of a `list`

```
sg = set()
for url in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.somewebsite")}):
    print(url['href'])
    sg.add(url['href'])
print(sg)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a **list**, using a **set** would solve the issue.

```
sg = set()
for url in soup.find_all('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("^https://www.somewebsite")}):
    print(url['href'])
    sg.add(url['href'])
print(sg)
```

Comment: I think the webpage has two separate NAV, one for desktop another for mobile. Beautifulsoup grabbing both, I guess.